# Count number of directories

Tags: find, directory, wc

I need a script or command that prints a number of directories which name begins from "lib" in whole directory subtree. I was trying to do it using find, grep, and wc but can't scan all directories. How to do it?

Comment: I replaced grub with grep; hope that's what you meant. Revert if not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
find . -type d -name lib\* -exec echo x \; | wc -l
```

Comment: That does run one `echo` command in a new process for each `lib*` directory though, which is not efficient.

Comment: I doubt there's any reason to use echo. `find . -type d -name lib\* -printf "%i\n" | wc -l` should be sufficient. Let `find` handle everything instead of calling extra process there.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy -printf is gnu specific

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas  didn't know. Will remember

Answer (score 5):

```
LC_ALL=C find .//. -name 'lib*' -type d | grep -c //
```

You can't use `find . | wc -l` as that wouldn't work properly if there are file paths with newline characters.

Without `LC_ALL=C` that could fail to count dir names that start with `lib` but where the rest of the name contains bytes that don't form valid characters.

With `zsh`:

```
(){echo $#} **/lib*(DN/)
```

Comment: Neat trick with `.//.`...

Comment: Wait, can you explain how does `.//.` work ?  I get the idea that `grep -c` should be able to count lines starting with that pattern, but it seems like after `./` should only be filenames and yet there's another slash dot there, and it still works. How ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy `.` is the current directory, which may also be spelled `./`.  Slashes can be repeated, so `.//` is still the current directory, and `.//.` is the same as well (`foo/.` is always the same as `foo`).  `find` will print its results relative to the root directory you specified, in this case like `.//./libwhatever`, `.//./foo/bar/libsomething`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all `lib`-directories have sane names with no newlines or other strange/exotic characters:

```
find / -type d -name "lib*" -print | wc -l
```

This assumes that you, by the "whole directory subtree", mean "anywhere". Change `/` into `.` to only count in the current directory or below.

The `find` command would find all directories (`-type d`) whose name start with `lib` (`-name "lib*"`) and print these (`-print`).

The `wc -l` would count the number of lines in the output from `find`.

Comment: I'm not sure about BSD find, but at least with GNU find  `-print` is default behavior, so we could leave that off, no ?  And as I commented on other answer, the strange/exotic filenames probably can be handled with `-printf "%i\n"` option instead

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bash-only solution, using `globstar` shell option:

```
$ shopt -s globstar; c=0; for f in ** ; do echo "${f##*/}"; [[ "${f##*/}" =~ ^lib* ]] && [[ -d "$f" ]]  && ((c++)); done ; echo $c
```

Or in script format for readability:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s globstar 
c=0
for f in **
do 
    echo "${f##*/}"
    if [[ "${f##*/}" =~ ^lib* ]] && [[ -d "$f" ]]
    then 
        ((c++))
    done
echo $c
```

`globstar` allows us to enable recursive globbing and via `[[` with pattern matching and `-d` flag to check if that's a directory, we increment the counter variable `$c`, which we print at the end.